# Does anyone know what marsupial this is?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

[image]

I know what this is a marsupial, but i'm not quite sure which one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why was this closed? Species identification questions [seem to be on topic](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/181/species-identification-questions) and this is no more localized than any other such question. @mad-scientist?

Comment: I think the OP could have included information like where the photo was taken? But still I am inclined to agree - I have seen many similar questions on here that were not closed.

Comment: @terdon I closed it mainly because it was self-answered in a very short time and because the question and the answer don't contain much detail

Comment: I had not taken the photo myself; I had received it from lecture notes that did not give any information about the photo. The reason I answered in such a short time after posting it was because I had asked an Australian friend of mine, and he got back to me not long after I had asked the question. So I thought it was best I answer it. As for the detail in the answer, the question was just relating the species, nothing else.

Comment: I can see how it looks suspicious though! Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I've been told it is the marsupial 'Myrmecobius fasciatus' commonly known as the numbat.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbat